# Manipulation of matrix of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-equations

$A \in M_{m \times 1}(\Bbb C),\ B \in M_{m \times n}(\Bbb C),\ C \in M_{n \times 1}(\Bbb C)$.  Now when I do matrix multiplication $A^\dagger BC$ where $A^\dagger$ represents the tranpose conjugate of the vector I get a complex number, say $a+ib$. I want to find the modulus squared of that, i.e. $|A^\dagger BC|^2$ but how do I represent this in terms of matrices?

I have the answer: $A^\dagger BCC^\dagger B^\dagger A$. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially we want to multiply $A^\dagger BC$ by its complex conjugate.  However, the conjugate transpose will also work (all $1\times 1$ matrices are transpose invariant).  So what is the conjugate transpose of $A^\dagger BC$?

Comment: I thinks its transpose conjugate of each matrix in reverse order. That is why answer is $A^\dagger BCC^\dagger B^\dagger A $. Am I right?

Comment: Yep: $[A^\dagger BC]^\dagger = C^\dagger B^\dagger A$ so just multiply the two "numbers" together to get the modulus squared.